# parse json structure from excel sheet into java

Tags: java, json, excel, apache-poi

i have a data in excel sheet that i need to read in java, i am able to read normal content but not able to read the json structure that i have stored. how can i parse json from excel to java?

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C://users/user/Desktop/C.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
        HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);

        HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.getCell((short) 2);
        String c1Val = cellC1.getStringCellValue();
        HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.getCell((short) 3);
        double d1Val = cellD1.getNumericCellValue();
        HSSFCell cellE1 = row1.getCell((short) 4);
        String e1Val = cellE1.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("C1: " + c1Val);
        System.out.println("D1: " + d1Val);
        System.out.println("E1: " + e1Val);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("name", new c1Val);

        System.out.print(obj);
                    }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

my excel sheet contains the following json:

```
     A      B                       C                            D        E  
     1      rap   {"type":"int", "minimum":15, "maximum":58}     240     delhi
```

this data needs to be read, from column c i need to read a single variable from 15 to 58.. how can i do this?

Comment: What isn't working with your code?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am not able to parse json structure ie. {"type":"int", "minimum:15", "maximum":58} into my program. how can i do this? By parsing this structure I need to read 1 value in my program between 15 to 58..

Comment: use gjson library to read the json

Comment: @swan can i perform the operation of reading the random variable from the following json structure {"type":"int", "minimum:15", "maximum":58}

Comment: yes you can read any value from that json structure if you are using Map get function

Comment: if you convert that json to object, you can directly use that attribute of that object.

Comment: if its helpful and correct for you accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse JSON into Java object in one line like this,

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

if your Json String value in `c1Val` then your json code will be like this.

```
Map<String,Object> c_data = mapper.readValue(c1Val, Map.class);
String minimum = c_data.get("minimum");
String maximum= c_data.get("maximum");
```